# Flowplayer Video not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

I have a link which on clicking takes me to a flowplayer video. My problem is that when I click the link, the flowplayer content just freezes and the video doesn't load. On console, I get a "api is undefined" error. However this is resolved once I refresh the page.

Why is this so ? Am I missing something ?

Even when I add the autoplay feature, the video plays but the flowplayer controls do not load. They load on refreshing the page again. I can't figure out what's wrong!

Have any of you encountered this ? This happens both on chrome and FF

Comment: can you add source code?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly what you need to do to correct your code without posting it, but `"api is undefined"` means you are using the variable `api` without first declaring and defining it.

To get a handle on the API within flowplayer you must first use the flowplayer function.  There are a couple of ways of doing this.

**1**

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) { 
    api.bind("load", function () { 
        // do something when a new video is about to be loaded 
    });
});
```

**2**

```
var api = flowplayer();
api.load();
```

Just using `api` without calling the flowplayer function will result in the error you are geting.

For more information on the flowplayer API please see their [documentation](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Init Flowplayer manually:

**HTML**

```
<div class="player">
   <video>
       <source src="Videos/video.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function () {
    $(".player").flowplayer({
        // add video player properties here            
    });
});
```

I tested it in ASP MVC4 and it's working.